# Validating text file content using Java

Tags: java, sql

This is the test.txt file
I am new in learning java. I want to search the latest or maximum date and time from this file.
My project is stuck here because of this please help me.

```
Event Date and Time="2013/06/24 16:53:45"
Event Date and Time="2013/06/24 16:53:46"
Event Date and Time="2013/06/24 16:53:41"
Event Date and Time="2013/06/24 16:53:33"
Event Date and Time="2013/06/24 16:53:25"
```

Here is my code what i do in while loop i cannot understand please help me

```
try {


        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(file); 
            DataInputStream in1= new DataInputStream(fstream1); 
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
        String line;
        line=bf.readLine();
        boolean myheader = checkHeader(line.trim());

            if(!myheader)
            {

            while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)

            {


               }
                 }
       catch(Exception)
                {
                     }


            private static boolean checkHeader(String headerString) {
    boolean result = true;
    String[] headerElements = headerString.split(":");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < headerElements.length; i++){
        if(i != headerElements.length - 1)
            list.add(headerElements[i] + ":");
        else
            list.add(headerElements[i]);
    }

    for(String listElements : list){
        if(!HEADER.contains(listElements)){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your title to be more concise. Almost every question on this site wants help.

Comment: Did you start writing any code or kept staring at it?

Comment: i am reading the file bt i dont know how to put condition in the code.

Comment: @user2508209 Whaterver you have tried just put that and let us know where you exactly stuck. You can make use of `Calendar` class.

Comment: brother i put my code above u can see it now.

Comment: @Smit u can see my code now

Comment: @Smit brother i can put my code above u can see it now

Comment: @user2508209 Yes I can see it, thanks. I have posted some pseudo code for you. I hope this helps..

Comment: how i close this question ? because i got the answer from @Smit

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo code for you, as I don't understand your code.

```
ArrayList ls = new ArrayList<String>();
Date date1 = null, date2 = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:ss:SS");

ls.add("2013/06/24 16:53:45");
ls.add("2013/06/24 16:53:46");
ls.add("2013/06/24 16:53:41");
ls.add("2013/06/24 16:53:48");

try {
    date1 = sdf.parse((String) ls.get(0));
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 1; i < ls.size(); i++) {
    try {
        date2 = sdf.parse((String) ls.get(i));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (date2.compareTo(date1) > 0) {
        date1 = date2;
    }
}

System.out.println("Latest Date :::::" + sdf.format(date1));
```

I hope this helps. If you have any question just ask.

Comment: @user2508209 If this solved your problem then accept the answer and close the question. I also put the comment for your splitting question.

Answer (score 1):

iterate your file store values to list and compare date value with each other by iterating loop .

Comment: ok i read the file but how i store value to list and compare date and time? can u provide me little bit code here please